# Displaying .avif images on versions lower than android 12

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-glide, android-image

Im wondering whether there is a library or a way to display .avif images on android versions lower than 12, since avif is supported from android 12+.

I tried using Glide and Picasso, but it just displays a empty view, when passing on an avif file format URL, on an android 9.0.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is such possibility. For example:
Screenshot in https://twitter.com/novomesk/status/1615032841502593026

"Index" application from mauikit.org uses Qt. Adding an Qt plug-in with AVIF support enables the application to open AVIF images.

Comment: i dont see any info on how it can be implemented in an android project

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used libavif library to display .avif images on versions lower than android 12.0.

https://github.com/maoabc/libavif-android

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).